# jS OOP nested functions

Tags: javascript, oop, function, nested

Ok this may be a noobolicious question as im new to OOP.

Im attempting to build something of a JS Object Library and was wondering if I could do it using nested functions??

```
var object = new function() {

    this.action1 = function () {
        this.dostuff1 = function () {
             return "dostuff1";
        };

     this.dostuff2 = function () {
          return "dostuff2";
     };                   
};
```

I am having trouble accessing the third level functions. Can I nest like this?

```
this.action2 = function () {
    return "action2";
}; 

alert(object.action1.dostuff2());
```

Comment: You can definitely create nested functions, but the problems you are having probably relate to use of the `this` keyword. Have you read up on [how `this` works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)? It's a bit different to what happens in class-based OO languages like Java.

Comment: There is a missing `};` to close `this.action1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below for some code cleanup:

```
var o = (new function () {          // changed 'object' to 'o'
  this.action1 = (function () {     // added parentheses, not required.
    this.dostuff1 = (function () {  // does not return anything.
      return "dostuff1";            // and is also not the proper way to organize
    });                             // ** look at the javascript prototype
    return this;                    // now it does
  });                               // missing closing bracket

  this.dostuff2 = (function () {
    return "dostuff2";
  });                   
});

alert(o.action1().dostuff2());      // action1 is a function, not a variable.
```

Hope this helps. Also, here's a [brief tutorial on the javascript prototype](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/objects).

Answer (score 3):

While Eberlin's answer is perfectly correct I'd suggest you to create a nested object which in turn again exposes functions rather than nesting functions itself. Otherwise this might become a maintainability nightmare.

Basically you could create

```
var Child = function(){
   //constructor
};

Child.prototype.doStuff2 = function(){
  return "dostuff2";
};

var Root = function(obj){
   //constructor
   this.child = obj;
};

Root.prototype.action1 = function(){
   return "doStuff1";
};

//usage
var myRoot = new Root(new Child());
myRoot.action1();
myRoot.child.action2();
```

Here's a live example: http://jsbin.com/ijotup/edit#javascript,live